# What happened in using L.CRS.EPSG4326 or not in leaflet？

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet

Not Use L.CRS.EPSG4326::

```
map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: [21.43078,51.12748],
    zoom: 13
});
```

Use L.CRS.EPSG4326:

```
map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: [21.43078,51.12748],
    zoom: 13,
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
});
```

The default epsg is what? (is EPSG:3857?), But Both I will input latlng, not xy meter, I think only Mercator-Projection(or other-projection) can be show in map. What happened in the process? And why will get different x,y index tile?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! It sounds unclear to me what you do not understand about the difference in the CRS. You might need first to make sure you know the difference between [map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), then their consequences on [tiling](https://www.maptiler.com/how-to/coordinates-bounds-projection/).